# VAE: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (90x12800 and 90x360)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, torch, autoencoder

I have CSI data with the following shape (5520, 90, 200) being samples, the stacked antennas and subcarriers and time frame. I am trying to build a variational autoencoder however I keep getting stuck on the training part as it says that the matrixes I am inputting cannot be multiplied.

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        
        x_dim = 90
        # Layer 1
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential()
        self.encoder.add_module('fc1', nn.Linear(x_dim, 360))
        self.encoder.add_module('Sigmoid1', nn.Sigmoid())
        self.encoder.add_module('BN1', nn.BatchNorm1d(360))
        self.encoder.add_module('DO1', nn.Dropout())
        
        # Layer 2
        self.encoder.add_module('fc2', nn.Linear(360, 50))
        self.encoder.add_module('Sigmoid2', nn.Sigmoid())
        self.encoder.add_module('BN2', nn.BatchNorm1d(50))
        self.encoder.add_module('DO2', nn.Dropout())

        # Latent 
        self.k_mu = nn.Linear(50, z_dim)
        self.k_sigma = nn.Linear(50, z_dim)
        
    def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
        eps = np.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
        return eps * tf.exp(logvar * .5) + mean
    
    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.encoder(x)
        k_mu = self.k_mu(h)
        k_sigma = self.k_sigma(h)
        z_dim = reparameterize(k_mu, log(k_sigma))
        return z_dim

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        x_dim = 90
        #1
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential()
        self.decoder.add_module('fc3', nn.Linear(z_dim, 50))
        self.decoder.add_module('Sigmoid3', nn.Sigmoid())
        self.decoder.add_module('BN3', nn.BatchNorm1d(50))
        self.decoder.add_module('DO3', nn.Dropout())
        #2
        self.decoder.add_module('fc4', nn.Linear(50, 360))
        self.decoder.add_module('Sigmoid4', nn.Sigmoid())
        self.decoder.add_module('BN4', nn.BatchNorm1d(360))
        self.decoder.add_module('DO4', nn.Dropout())
        self.decoder.add_module('x_recon', nn.Linear(360, x_dim))
        
    def forward(self, z):
        x_ = self.decoder(z)
        return x_

class VAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim):
        super(VAE, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(z_dim)   
        self.decoder = Decoder(z_dim)
    
    def sample(self, z_mu, z_log_var):
        z_std = torch.exp(z_log_var)
        eps = torch.randn_like(z_std)
        z = z_mu + z_std*eps 
        return z

    def forward(self, x):
        # Encode
        z_mu, z_log_var = self.encoder(x)
        
        # Sample
        if self.training:
          # Sample if we are training
            z = self.sample(z_mu, z_log_var)
        else:
            z = z_mu

        # Decode
        x_ = self.decoder(z) 
        return x_, z_mu, z_log_var

vae = VAE(z_dim=10).cuda()

optimizer = optim.Adam(vae.parameters())

epochs = 20 #Number of epochs

# Loop over epochs
for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    vae.train()
    train_loss = 0
    # Loop over batches. Note that the labels are ignored in this case
    for batch_idx, (data) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        data = data.cuda()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        data = data.view(data.size(1), -1)
        x_recon, z_mu, z_log_var = vae(data)
        
        # Calculate the loss
        KL_loss, E_loss = loss_function(x_recon, data, z_mu, z_log_var)
        loss = KL_loss + E_loss
        loss.backward()

        # Accumulate the loss to calculate the average
        train_loss += loss.item()
        
        # Step the optimizer
        optimizer.step()
        
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tKL Loss: {:.6f}\tBC Loss: {:.6f}\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), KL_loss.item() / len(data), E_loss.item() / len(data), loss.item() / len(data)))
    print('====> Epoch: {} Average loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)))
```

And I get the following error: `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (90x12800 and 90x360)`
I cannot figure out why I am getting it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a toy example of the data which easily can be converted into a data loader object :)

Comment: Hi! The data that has been used comes from the SignFi paper. Here's a link to the Github https://github.com/yongsen/SignFi I used the dataset_lab_276_dl.mat file, calculated the amplitude, used onehotencoding for the label and created the data loader object!